# Get all lines in log matching a date in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, logging

I would like to get all lines that match a date from a log file. This works fine:

```
Get-Content $filepath | Out-String -stream | Select-String $yesterday
```

However, when I try to add this to a string that is used for my output, it seems to stick all lines together into a single line:

```
$out += Get-Content $filepath | Out-String -stream | Select-String $yesterday
```

Something wrong with my approach here. I basically just want to get each line (each on a single line!) from the log file that matches the date string for yesterday that I've built? Is there a good simple way to do this please?

First four lines from log:

```
10.79.69.226:9300   3096    2021-03-26 07:56:10.058 +1                  Default Executor-thread-6350    caf 2047    2   Audit.dispatcher.caf    Request         Warning     secure error - did not find userCapabilities
10.79.69.226:9300   3096    2021-03-26 07:56:10.136 +1  86CBF1D67841D67F3486E6696FC77CF94E0364CD616B4A2FF18E72D6B40F5D71    88jh8Csq2q2jC4Ch4qysjqyCGdwwvM4lqwM9v8vd        D6F1761A9AB9A34301786A6A8DA18024001786d123647   TaskRunner:61   JSM 12  3   Audit.RTUsage.JSM                   [ContentManagerServiceClientPortImpl] Error when authenticating; response envelope is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:faults="http://www.w3.org/2001/09/soap-faults" xmlns:bus="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">   <SOAP-ENV:Header>      <bus:biBusHeader xsi:type="bus:biBusHeader">        <dispatcherTransportVars xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:dispatcherTransportVar[]">           <dispatcherTransportVars xsi:type="bus:dispatcherTransportVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">requester</name>                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">MS:Run Task</value>            </dispatcherTransportVars>          <dispatcherTransportVars xsi:type="bus:dispatcherTransportVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">NoQueueing</name>               <value xsi:type="xsd:string">true</value>           </dispatcherTransportVars>                  </dispatcherTransportVars>      <hdrSession xsi:type="bus:hdrSession">          <environmentVars xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:environmentVar[2]">              <environmentVars xsi:type="bus:environmentVar">                     <name xsi:type="xsd:string">SERVER_NAME</name>                  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">localhost</value>              </environmentVars>              <item xsi:type="bus:environmentVar">                    <name xsi:type="xsd:string">WEB_CONTENT_ROOT</name>                     <value xsi:type="xsd:string">/p2pd</value>              </item>             </environmentVars>          <bus:formFieldVars xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:formFieldVar[0]"/>                         <setCookieVars xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:setCookieVar[2]">              <item xsi:type="bus:setCookieVar">                  <name xsi:type="xsd:string">CRN</name>                  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">linesPerPage%3D15%26displayMode%3Dlist%26columnsPerPage%3D3%26showOptionSummary%3Dtrue%26format%3DHTML%26productLocale%3Den%26http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.cognos.com%2Fceba%2Fconstants%2FbiDirectionalOptionEnum%23biDirectionalFeaturesEnabled%3Dfalse%26showHints%3DshowAll%26showHiddenObjects%3Dfalse%26http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.cognos.com%2Fceba%2Fconstants%2FsystemOptionEnum%23accessibilityFeatures%3Dfalse%26showWelcomePage%3Dtrue%26backgroundSessionLogging%3D1970-01-01%2B00%253A00%253A00%26listViewSeparator%3Dnone%26skin%3Dcorporate%26timeZoneID%3DEurope%252FBerlin%26contentLocale%3Den%26automaticPageRefresh%3D30%26</value>                     <maxAge xsi:type="xsd:int">0</maxAge>               </item>                 <item xsi:type="bus:setCookieVar">                  <name xsi:type="xsd:string">userCapabilities</name>                     <value xsi:type="xsd:string"/>                  <maxAge xsi:type="xsd:int">-1</maxAge>              </item>             </setCookieVars>        </hdrSession>       <tracking xsi:type="bus:tracking">          <hopCount xsi:type="xsd:integer">1</hopCount>           <requestContext xsi:type="xsd:string">2dMqGqCGs4jj2wMjqjGjC9q9ydjjs8qljl4wj2vl</requestContext>             <sessionContext xsi:type="xsd:string">f:1:null</sessionContext>             <providers xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:provider[1]">              <provider xsi:type="bus:provider">                  <name xsi:type="xsd:string">cm</name>                   <patch xsi:type="xsd:int">1</patch>                     <build xsi:type="xsd:string">11.0</build>               </provider>             </providers>        </tracking>         <bus:userPreferenceVars xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="bus:userPreferenceVar[18]">           <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">linesPerPage</name>                 <value xsi:type="xsd:string">15</value>             </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">displayMode</name>              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">list</value>           </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">columnsPerPage</name>               <value xsi:type="xsd:string">3</value>          </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">showOptionSummary</name>                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">true</value>           </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">format</name>               <value xsi:type="xsd:string">HTML</value>           </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">productLocale</name>                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">en</value>             </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">http://developer.cognos.com/ceba/constants/biDirectionalOptionEnum#biDirectionalFeaturesEnabled</name>              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">false</value>          </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">showHints</name>                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">showAll</value>            </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">showHiddenObjects</name>                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">false</value>          </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">http://developer.cognos.com/ceba/constants/systemOptionEnum#accessibilityFeatures</name>                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">false</value>          </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">http://developer.cognos.com/ceba/constants/biDirectionalOptionEnum#baseTextDirection</name>                 <value xsi:type="xsd:string">http://developer.cognos.com/ceba/constants/baseTextDirectionEnum#Auto</value>          </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">showWelcomePage</name>              <value xsi:type="xsd:string">true</value>           </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">backgroundSessionLogging</name>                 <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1970-01-01 00:00:00</value>            </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">listViewSeparator</name>                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">none</value>           </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">skin</name>                 <value xsi:type="xsd:string">corporate</value>          </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">timeZoneID</name>               <value xsi:type="xsd:string">Europe/Berlin</value>          </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">contentLocale</name>                <value xsi:type="xsd:string">en</value>             </item>             <item xsi:type="bus:userPreferenceVar">                 <name xsi:type="xsd:string">automaticPageRefresh</name>                 <value xsi:type="xsd:string">30</value>             </item>         </bus:userPreferenceVars>       </bus:biBusHeader>  <faults:Misunderstood qname="bus:CM">       <errorDetailDocument xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/">          <errorCode>cmAuthenticateTCInvalidReference</errorCode>             <errorMessage>CM-HDR-4012 The search path &quot;CAMID(&quot;ING_PROD:u:uid=ic04yq&quot;)/credential&quot; does not select one credential object.</errorMessage>         </errorDetailDocument>  </faults:Misunderstood>   </SOAP-ENV:Header>   <SOAP-ENV:Body>  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>        <faultcode>Client</faultcode>       <faultstring>CM-REQ-4342 An error occurred with the client.</faultstring>       <detail>            <bus:exception>                 <severity>error</severity>              <errorCode>caf</errorCode>              <bus:message>                   <messageString>CM-REQ-4159 Content Manager returned an error in the response header. The error &quot;cmAuthenticateTCInvalidReference CM-HDR-4012 The search path &quot;CAMID(&quot;ING_PROD:u:uid=ic04yq&quot;)/credential&quot; does not select one credential object.&quot; can be found in the response SOAP header.</messageString>                </bus:message>          </bus:exception>        </detail>   </SOAP-ENV:Fault>   </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>   
10.79.69.226:9300   3096    2021-03-26 07:56:10.183 +1  B96DF6E61B52E9BF15C76930D9BC5C08C9375906D3F5A04E6B6B5EBC1D50FD60    lsj8jyhswC8vlGdhsqlMvMq4GGqdd2lM2vCdh29C            Default Executor-thread-7091    CM  12  3   Audit.Other.cms.CM  ADD HISTORYDETAIL   /Team Content/Misys reports/7.3/7.3.1182 Facility Overview Detail by Lender_NEW/2021-03-26T06:56:10.089Z/[historyDetail]    Success     
10.79.69.226:9300   3096    2021-03-26 07:56:10.152 +1  86CBF1D67841D67F3486E6696FC77CF94E0364CD616B4A2FF18E72D6B40F5D71    88jh8Csq2q2jC4Ch4qysjqyCGdwwvM4lqwM9v8vd        D6F1761A9AB9A34301786A6A8DA18024001786d123647   TaskRunner:61   MS  12  3   Audit.RTUsage.ms.MS                 Failed to run task [com.cognos.monitor.tse.BiBusRunContext taskID=D6F1761A9AB9A34301786A6A8DA18024001786d123647].  Error is: CNC-MON-3600 An error occurred running the object on the target service. Consult the log files.
```

Comment: Why are you including `Out-String` in the pipe? What goes wrong with `Get-Content $filepath | Select-String $yesterday`? (_`Get-Content` is the cmdlet that `cat` is an alias for._)

Comment: If I take out `Out-String` it still ends up shoving every line together into a single line. I just can't get it such that each line of the output in `$out` are individual lines. Every time, all of the hundreds of lines are mashed into a single line. 

Comment: If `Get-Content` is mashing every line together into a single string there is a very high chance there is something wrong with your file. `Get-Content` is supposed to autosplit in `\r\n`, meaning that the result of your file should ve a variable of the type `object[]`.

Comment: Please show us a couple of lines from the log file, so we can see what date format it uses

Comment: I've put four lines into the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you want:

```
$yesterday = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$log = Get-Content -Path $filepath
$out = Join-Path -Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($filepath)) -ChildPath ("log_{0}.log" -f $yesterday)
# use SimpleMatch because the pattern is to be taken literally (no regex)
($log | Select-String -Pattern $yesterday -SimpleMatch).Line | Set-Content -Path $out
```

An alternative without using `Get-Content`:

```
$yesterday = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$out = Join-Path -Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($filepath)) -ChildPath ("log_{0}.log" -f $yesterday)
# use SimpleMatch because the pattern is to be taken literally (no regex)
(Select-String -Path $filepath -Pattern $yesterday -SimpleMatch).Line | Set-Content -Path $out
```

Comment: This technique worked for me, many thanks. The other answer looks great on paper, but unfortunately, I had some encoding issue that meant that the output was unusable. 

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't count as answer but I guess this is easily explained with a screenshot. Let me know if you understand what you see in the screenshot so I can delete this answer after.

Basically there is no need to `$out +=`.

Edit: You just need to change the `.tostring` to `.tostring('yyyy-MM-dd')`. This should work fine for your file. I'm displaying the first 100 chars of your log file because it is huge.

[image]

Comment: I get what you are doing for sure (`$yesterday` above contains exactly that in fact) 

Comment: ok, I think it's heading in the right direction, but now I get things like there is an encoding issue `i S r t o . e r  n C t  a h a  e s f C o f o n r - i r o  f C t n o g r r S e S C n n n N  g t i  a 1 2 t 2 r f f  g . . r t s t N l s`. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I think that might be because of `Out-String -Stream` are you still using it?

Comment: No, it's long gone, going purely with your approach. 

Comment: If you upload a screenshot of what you see and update what your code looks like, I might be able to help. One thing to consider is, your file has some lines that are actually huge and I mean 9207 chars long, so even tho you see the output on your PS host as if there is an encoding issue if you export the result to a txt file the issue might not be there.